# Return Html page loaded with JSON data in NodeJS

Tags: html, json, node.js

I have a NodeJs server that fetches JSon data from a rest API.

Once the data is loaded, I'd like to return an HTML page and load it in a table there.

**EDIT**

*I figured out that I needed express (example below updated), with the right version (3.x to old!) to use res.SendFile(). So the Html file is returned now. However still don't know how to load the data in the page.*

Ideally I'd also want to be able to filter on the data using [datatables](https://datatables.net/).

**NodeJS server route**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var path = require('path');
const Request = require('request');
const ServerAddress = ...;

exports.showAll = function(req, res) {
    Request.get(ServerAddress + '/data', function (error, response, body) {
        if (error) {
            throw error;
        }
        const data = JSON.parse(body);
        return res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname + '/../index.html'), { result: data });
    });
```

**index.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="data">
            <table id="resultsTable">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Col1</th>
                        <th>Col2</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest EJS. It works great in Node and is easy to pick up if you only know HTML.
http://www.embeddedjs.com/getting_started.html
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ejs

Comment: Thank you. I actually have used another similar framework http://handlebarsjs.com/, but would want to not use any if possible so I can handle table filtering etc. that I didn't seem to be able to do through it since too much hiding the JS functionalities... I may be wrong though, I am a js beginner